# Adding Devkit to environmental path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Despite installing dev tools correctly (at least, following the documentation word for word), I keep getting this error:

```
C:\devkit>gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

How can I add the build tools to my Path?

In Windows 7, I know I can edit my path by navigating to

```
Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables
```

I've installed Devkit at `c:/Devkit`

But that's all I know. How can I add Devkit to my Environment Variables (at least, I think that's what it means)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add Devkit to your Environment Variables doing the following from within `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables`:

- Add a new "System Variable"

  -- Variable Name: `DEVKIT_HOME`

  -- Variable Value: `C:\Devkit`
- Edit System "Path" variable's value by appending the following:

  --`;%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\mingw\bin`
- Of course the final step: "Reboot the machine".

You could of course skip adding `DEVKIT_HOME` variable and directly update the `Path` variable with `C:\Devkit\bin;C:\Devkit\mingw\bin`.